# Contar números 1 em número binário após conversão de base decimal

Tags: c, algoritmo, matemática

Nesse programa eu preciso contar a quantidade de números 1 presentes no número binário após a conversão da base decimal. Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main ()
{

    char valor[1000], tmp;
    long long int count, valor_i, valor_c = 0, r_div, i, count2;

    scanf("%lld", &valor_i);

    count = 0;
    i = 0;

    while (i != 1)
    {
        r_div =  valor_i / 2;

        if (r_div < 2)
        {
            i = 1;
            if(valor_i % 2 == 0)
            {
                valor[count] = '0';
            }
            else
            {
                valor[count] = '1';
            }
            if(r_div == 0)
            {
                valor[count + 1] = '0';
            }
            else
            {
                valor[count + 1] = '1';
            }
            valor[count + 2] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            if (valor_i % 2 == 0)
            {
                valor[count] = '0';
            }
            else
            {
                valor[count] = '1';
            }
        }
        count++;
        valor_i = r_div;
    }

    count2 = strlen(valor) - 1;

    for(count = 0; count == count2 || count < count2; count++)
    {
        tmp = valor[count];
        valor[count] = valor[count2];
        valor[count2] = tmp;
        count2--;
    }
    printf("%s\n", valor);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema dele? Esse código não está contando a quantidade de 1 presente. Esse é o problema?

Comment: @bigown é por isso que eu acho que estas perguntas deviam estar fechadas, começam a surgir respostas de todo o tipo e nem se sabe qual é o real problema.

Comment: @JorgeB. Por isso eu respondi :P já que todo mundo estava respondendo sem ter muito detalhe, fui na onda. Eu acho que dá para inferir o que inferiram, mas não é 100% certo que é o que ele quer.

Comment: @bigown nem 50% sequer. O problema é que o pessoal quer ganhar rep e não tem nada de mal, mas dar o resultado não vai ajudar nada o AP.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples de fazer isso:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char valor[1000];
    long long int valor_i;
    int position = 0, count = 0;
    scanf("%lld", &valor_i);
    while (valor_i > 0) { //não precisa de flag, use a condição que encerra o laço
        int bit = valor_i % 2; //descobre se é 0 ou 1
        valor[position++] = '0' + bit; //adiciona o caractere de acordo com o bit calculado
        count += bit; //adiciona 0 ou 1 no contador
        valor_i /= 2; //vamos pra próxima, resolvemos metade do valor
    }
    valor[position] = '\0'; //termina a string
    size_t size = strlen(valor); //vai começar inverter a string
    for (int count = 0; count <= size / 2 - 1; count++) { //basta inverter até a metade
        char tmp = valor[count];
        valor[count] = valor[size - count - 1]; //não precisa de dois contadores
        valor[size - count - 1] = tmp;
    }
    printf("%s - quantidade de '1' => %d\n", valor, count);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oM26k4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qkxahsqm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountZeros.c).

Mudei um pouco os nomes das variáveis, mas deixei a principais, apesar de não concordar com elas.

Organizei o código e simplifiquei-o, fazendo só o necessário usando matemática.

A grande mudança para resolver a contagem de 1 foi colocar um contador dentro do laço somando sempre que fosse um.

Eu preferia ter algumas restrições e facilitar o algoritmo, mas deixei como está. Poderia evitaria ter que fazer a inversão. Fiz um exemplo [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/q79OlW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/feguefam-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountZeros2.c).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main() {
    char binario[64];
    memset(binario, '0', 63);
    binario[63] = '\0';
    int64_t decimal;
    scanf("%jd", &decimal);
    int position = 62, count = 0;
    while (decimal > 0) {
        int bit = decimal & 1;
        binario[position--] = '0' + bit;
        count += bit;
        decimal /= 2;
    }
    printf("%s - quantidade de '1' => %d", &binario[position + 1], count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use um `for`:

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(valor); i++){

     if(valor[i]=='1'){
        count++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O algoritmo capaz de resolver o problema proposto é conhecido por vários nomes: `Hamming Weight`, `Population Count`, `popcount` ou `Sideways Sum`.

A Wikipedia possui um excelente artigo falando profundamente sobre o assunto [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

Existe uma solução para esse problema proposta no `Capítulo 2.9` da Segunda edição do [famoso livro](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Kernighan-Ritchie/C-Programming-Ebook.pdf) "The C Programming Language" publicado pela dupla "Kernighan & Ritchie".

Segue uma função (testada e comentada) capaz de contar a quantidade de bits setados na representação binária de um número decimal, baseada na solução proposta no livro:

```
int popcount( unsigned int num )
{
    unsigned int count = 0; /* Inicia o contador com 0  */

    while( num ) /* Enquanto houverem bits setados... */
    {
        num &= num - 1; /* Limpa o bit setado mais significante */

        count++; /* Incrementa contador de bits setados */
    }

    return count; /* Retorna o contador */
}
```

Segue código completo capaz de resolver o problema:

```
/* ************************************************************************** */
/* *                              popcount.c                                * */
/* ************************************************************************** */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char * byte_to_binary( unsigned int num )
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    static char str[ 100 ] = {0};

    strcpy( str, "" );

    for( i = 128; i > 0; i >>= 1 )
        strcat( str, ((num & i) == i) ? "1" : "0");

    return str;
}


int popcount( unsigned int num )
{
    unsigned int count = 0;

    while( num )
    {
        num &= num - 1;

        count++;
    }

    return count;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf( "dec=%d, hex=0x%x, bin=%s, popcount=%d\n", i, i, byte_to_binary(i), popcount(i) );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
$ ./popcount 
dec=0, hex=0x0, bin=00000000, popcount=0
dec=1, hex=0x1, bin=00000001, popcount=1
dec=2, hex=0x2, bin=00000010, popcount=1
dec=3, hex=0x3, bin=00000011, popcount=2
dec=4, hex=0x4, bin=00000100, popcount=1
dec=5, hex=0x5, bin=00000101, popcount=2
dec=6, hex=0x6, bin=00000110, popcount=2
dec=7, hex=0x7, bin=00000111, popcount=3
dec=8, hex=0x8, bin=00001000, popcount=1
dec=9, hex=0x9, bin=00001001, popcount=2
dec=10, hex=0xa, bin=00001010, popcount=2
dec=11, hex=0xb, bin=00001011, popcount=3
dec=12, hex=0xc, bin=00001100, popcount=2
dec=13, hex=0xd, bin=00001101, popcount=3
dec=14, hex=0xe, bin=00001110, popcount=3
dec=15, hex=0xf, bin=00001111, popcount=4
```

Espero ter ajudado!